# I can not get this PDO insert query to work

Tags: php, pdo

Here is some code I am working on.  I want to keep track of some data like my password to my online connections and want to be able to get the correct password back if I forget.

Here is my code that does not work.

```
if(isset($_GET['addform']))
    {
        include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'../rcadb/db.inc.php';

        try
            {
                $sql='INSERT INTO rcainfo
                        SET
                        coname = :coname,
                        coemail = :coemail,
                        copassword = AES_ENCRYPT(:copassword, $passwordHelper) ';

                $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
                $s->bindValue(':coname', $_POST['coname']);
                $s->bindValue(':coemail', $_POST['coemail']);
                $s->bindValue(':copassword', $_POST['copassword']);
                $s->execute();
            }
        catch(PDOException $e)
            {
                $error = 'Error adding submitted Company Data';
                include 'error.html.php';
                exit();
            }   
        header('Location:.');
        exit(); 
    }
```

I have a form that I enter the data into etc.

any help will be apreciated

Comment: [Don't limit passwords](http://jayblanchard.net/security_fail_passwords.html)  and [use the proper methods to hash passwords with PHP](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html).

Comment: Thank you for the advise, but I am not using the password as a password.  It is data and I need to see it , to reference for some forms that I fill out.  I did get this working.  Had do do a couple of things and not sure what made it work but I had to put  " around the $passwordHelper variable and I used bindParam and it started working.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have an issue with your include:

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'../rcadb/db.inc.php';
```

Try using require instead of include becuase it will throw an error. Include doesn not throw an error.

My guess is that you probably just want to do this

```
$include = '../rcadb/db.inc.php';
require $include;
```

Comment: no that works.  The problem is with the AES_Encrypt,   I did get it working.  I did not show you all of my code.  Thanks tons for all the help